# I am new to reactjs. I am working on a dummy project to learn react, need help to export CSV and xls format to download file from table data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        if (data.data.length > 0) {

          var temp = "";
          data.data.forEach((itemData) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.id + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_salary + "</td></tr>";
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Fetching data from above API and showing in a table. Need help in to export all the data in csv and xls format and download by clicking on the folder**

Comment: This is not a "We code it for you" site. What have you tried to achieve your desired result? What went wrong, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @cloned thanks for your comment. if you know any link, document or blog, you can share the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Great place to start: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe

Stackblitz also is a fantastic playground if you don't have the toolchain set up locally: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8az7tw?file=src%2FApp.js

In React, you virtaully never interact with the DOM directly - e.g. using `document` APIs (like `document.getElementById` is a no-no. If you find yourself reaching for them (adding event listeners this way -  `element.addEventListener` - is also wrong), stop yourself, you're doing it wrong.

The react version of doing what you want would be roughly something like this:

```
const MyApp = () => {

  const [dataFromApi,setDataFromApi] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFromApi().then(data => setDataFromApi(data))
  },[])

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data">
          {dataFromApi.map(data => (
             <tr>
                {/* spit out your HTML for each row in here */}
             </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )


}
```

Comment: Thanks @adam for correction! Can you please let me know how to export CSV and xls format to download file from table data.

Comment: @dev123 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv or https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv